# Parse mail data from postfix in php (search mime-parser/decoder class)

Tags: php, email, parsing, mime, postfix-mta

I need to **parse mail** *received from postfix* **in php structure** like as headers array, plain/text body string and html body string.

I'm testing the examples from https://www.thecodingmachine.com/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail/ for receive all letters to my php-script. But examples from this page is abandoned or not work like as I want.

**I would like to have something like:**

```
$message_from_postfix = "Received: from [127.0.0.1] (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
        by DavidUbuntu (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 740AD380597
        for <david@localhost>; Thu,  5 Jan 2012 10:04:48 +0100 (CET)
Message-ID: <1325754288.4989.6.camel@DavidUbuntu>
Subject: my title
From: David Negrier <david@localhost>
To: david@localhost
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2012 10:04:48 +0100
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Mailer: Evolution 3.2.0- 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Mime-Version: 1.0

my mail content";

$data = ParseMessage($message_from_postfix);

echo $data->headers()['from']; // david@localhost
echo $data->headers()['to']; // david@localhost
echo $data->headers()['date']; // 1325757888
echo $data->text_message(); // my mail content
echo $data->html_message(); // (empty)
```

Comment: Do you have anything to start with? have you tried using a regex like this preg_match("/(From:)(.*)(<)(.*)(>)/", $input_line, $output_array);

Comment: Tlacaelel Ramon Luis, LOL. NO!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site where we do all the work for you. If you have a specific problem after you have tried something, then you can ask and we will try to help you, but we are not going to solve a problem like this for you just like that.

Comment: I'm not asking to solve the problem for me. Moreover, I probably already have found their own solution in the form of php-mime-mail-parser package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found: https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser

This is probably the best solution for me.